# How to ask for the meaning of a word or phrase?

Tags: american-english, expressions, british-english, spoken-english

I'd like to ask about the meaning of something, but I'm confused between these two sentences:

> 1. What is the meaning about "~~~~"?
> 2. what does it mean "~~~"?

Can I use both expressions when I am asking for the meaning?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ask for the meaning of a word, you can use the following:

> What does "**~~~**" mean?

or

> What is the meaning **of** "**~~~**"?

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are nearly right.

For the first sentence, the word [meaning](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meaning) is normally followed by the preposition **of**. You can often work out what prepositions are used with a particular word by looking it up in a dictionary that provides examples. Here is an example from the link that I provided above:

> The meaning **of** his gesture was clear.

The correct sentence is therefore:

> What is the meaning **of** "~~~~"?

In the second example, we only use **it** to refer to something that we have already mentioned in a **previous** sentence. So, this works:

> "~~~": what does it mean?

Alternatively, we can use the word [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/this) to refer to something that we are pointing at, or holding, or nearby, or is before or after in the text. You can therefore use **this** refer to something that follows in the text.

> what does **this** mean: "~~~"?

Answer (score 0):

Both of them weren't well suited.
`what does it mean '_________'?`: This statement can be used when you are pointing out to certain thing or a statement and then asking what it is?

According to me it is better to ask , in this way, `What does this word mean?` (While you are pointing out to a particular word.)

OR

`What does '________' mean?` :"When you are able to pronounce it."

and by the way, `Can I use both expression when I asking for the meaning?`

This is wrong, you are supposed to say: `Can I use both expressions while, I would like to ask for a meaning?`

OR

Something else if you find something better.